# How to update textView properly?

Tags: java, android, xml

Hello I am following a book tutorial on learning Android but the book is outdated. I'm getting a "String literal cannot be translated" and "Do not concatenate text with setText". I am wondering what is the correct method to update a TextView? I think that's what I essentially want to do.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textScore"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Score: 999"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textOperator"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textOperator" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textLevel"`enter code here`
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Level: 4"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="11dp" />
```

and here is the Java.

```
    textObjectScore.setText("Score:" + currentScore);
    textObjectLevel.setText("Level:" + currentLevel);
```

Comment: What happens if you create a `String textToSet = "Score: " + currentScore;` then `textObjectScore.setText(textToSet);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these have to do with translations.

"String literal cannot be translated".  This is a warning telling you that this string will be in english no matter what language the user changes their phone to.  For a professional app, you would define your string in strings.xml and use that string in your app.  That allows the string to be chosen for the phone's locale, assuming you've provided translation files.

"Do not concatenate text with setText".  There's no actual problem with doing this in your native language.  The problem is that in other languages, what you're doing may not make grammatical sense.  Instead you should define a string with input variables in strings.xml and use getString to fill in those variables.

But for throwing something together quickly that isn't going for international release you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guidelines (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html). For example specify your score-related string like this:

```
<string name="score">Score: %1$d</string>
```

And set it like this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String text = res.getString(R.string.score, currentScore);
textObjectScore.setText(text);
```

This way you can translate strings, provide plurals and format safely.